# Unable to get logback-spring.xml property file using Spring Cloud Config and Discovery

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul, spring-logback

I'm using [Discovery first bootstrap](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.4.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#discovery-first-bootstrap) feature and Consul as a Discovery Server, url to Config Server is located during start-up and I was able to get `application.properties`. I need also to get `logback-spring.xml` configuration from Config server and I don't know how.

What should I specify in `logging.config={???}logback-spring.xml` property to not hardcode url to Config Server?

Before Consul integration I was using url formed according to [Serving Plain text documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text) with hardcoded Config server url in properties and it was working fine, but now we want to avoid this.

From what I debugged there is no usage of Discovery client during reinitializing logging system in `PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used [Customizing Bootstrap Configuration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_customizing_the_bootstrap_configuration) to resolve my issue in a 'custom' way because I didn't find the solution in the documentation and source code.

Example: Add new file `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` and add there custom bootstrap configuration: `org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=sample.custom.CustomPropertySourceLocator`

In CustomPropertySourceLocator create property that will point to config server url (looked up via discovery)

```
@Configuration
public class CustomPropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {

  private final String configServiceName;
  private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

  public CustomPropertySourceLocator(
      @Value("${spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id}") String configServiceName,
      DiscoveryClient discoveryClient){
    this.configServiceName = configServiceName;
    this.discoveryClient = discoveryClient;
  }

  @Override
  public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {
    List<ServiceInstance> instances = this.discoveryClient.getInstances(this.configServiceName);
    ServiceInstance serviceInstance = instances.get(0);

    return new MapPropertySource("customProperty",
      Collections.singletonMap("configserver.discovered.uri", serviceInstance.getUri()));
  }
}
```

In code above we created custom property source that will have one property `configserver.discovered.uri`. We can use this property in our code (using @Value) or in other property files (even if they are located in the config-server storage).

`logging.config=${configserver.discovered.uri}/<path to the text file>/logback-spring.xml`
where `<path to text file>` should be formed according to the [Serving Plain Text Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html) and the way how you configured your config-server.