# Spring Cloud Config serving plain text does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to fetch configuration as a plain text as explained here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text

But I can fetch only for .properties, .yml, .json. For other formats like .config, .text, .xml I'm getting 404.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should modify with a few things on the your config server's properties/yaml.

```
logging.config=${spring.cloud.config.uri}/*/default/master/logback.xml.
```

etc. Also please share your config server yml with us. This information is not enough.
For More information

[can spring cloud config manage xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735668/can-spring-cloud-config-manage-xml-file)

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html